# Using XPath to query xml resource in Java using Android SDK

Tags: java, android, xpath

NOTE:  I'm modifying this from the orignial question.

I have an xml file in my /res/xml folder named "festivals.xml".  I'm using the following code to create an XmlResourceParser:

```
xrp = rc.getResources().getXml(R.xml.festivals);
```

However, although the file is there and it appears in the drop-down list in the IDE while typing, i.e., "R.xml.festivals"), when the above line executes nothing comes back.

I don't know what else to do.  I'm targeting 2.3.3 and 8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your xml file in the folder called raw and then you can access by this foolow R.raw.xyz